# Htmlunit: publish a link on Facebook

Tags: java, facebook, htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit to post link on my Fb wall page, but if I try to publish links, FB shows only the url without image, title ecc;

An alternative way could to be send a POST request to publish the entire link with all the information.

How can i build the Post request to publish a link on my fb page?

Answer (score 0):

In order to build a `POST` request you will have to use the [`WebRequest`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebRequest.html#WebRequest%28java.net.URL,%20com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpMethod%29) class.

You should use it this way:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
WebRequest wr = new WebRequest(new URL("http://url.to.post"), HttpMethod.POST);
List<NameValuePair> parameters = Arrays.asList(
        new NameValuePair("name", "john"),
        new NameValuePair("age", "28"));
wr.setRequestParameters(parameters);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(wr);
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Make sure you import:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.NameValuePair;
```

Instead of the Apache interface with the same name.

You will have to use Chrome's inspector or Firebug in order to see exactly what URL to post to as well as the parameters you need to send.

Comment: [link](http://s17.postimg.org/3rknou65r/Untitled.png)
which of these? and what parameters?